# Change values of array elements in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to change the value of specific elements in array. The array is of objects with two fields. Here is what my view outputs:

[image: Screenshot]

Each line there corresponds to the index of that object within the array. There is a **name** field (string) and a **progress** field (int) within the goals array. The input box displays the current value stored in the database and I would like it update to whatever value I enter. For example, if I changed '25' to '30' it should update to '30' after I push the button on the right.

If I were able to access the name, it would make it easier to locate the right object within the array. However, I am not sure how I would do that from within the view and corresponding input box.

Here is an entry in the database to demonstrate further:

[image: DB Document]

Here is the controller function I have so far. It finds the right document but it is failing actually update. Furthermore, the function should be able to update the correct index in the array based on

```html
const managerChangeGoalProgress = async (req, res) => {
  await Employee.updateOne( {_id: req.params.id}, {$set: {"goals.progress" : req.body}} );
  req.flash('success', 'Succesfully Updated Goal!');
  res.redirect(`managers/employees/${req.params.id}/goals`);
};
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: shouldn;t goals.progress be goals[0].progress

Comment: I tried that just now. It did not update. Also, the goal is to have it be dynamic so 0 would be a different index based on its position within the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore js or lodash to do this operatio.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little further?

Comment: You can use _.find(array,function(obj) {//do your search criteria}). This will find the exact element from the array. You can refer lodash or underscore js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an alternative solution. First I changed it from being several forms to one form which means one button, which is better I realized. req.body returns all values from the input boxes in the form of an array. It took me a while to find the correct syntax for the update function because it was not accepting the js variables I had in the for loop. It turns out it is necessary to wrap the variable in the first parameter after $set in brackets. Here is the code:

```
const managerChangeGoalProgress = async (req, res) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < req.body.progress.length; i++) {
    var setValue = "goals." + i.toString() + ".progress";
    var change = req.body.progress[i];
    await Employee.update( {_id: req.params.id},  {$set: { [setValue] : change }});
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
const managerChangeGoalProgress = async (req, res) => {
    let employee = await Employee.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).exec();
    employee.goals[index].progress=req.body.progress //change to your variable, index is your postion you want to change
    await employee.save();
    req.flash('success', 'Succesfully Updated Goal!');
    res.redirect(`managers/employees/${req.params.id}/goals`);
  };
```